# SQL delete where column = *

Tags: sql, request

How can I delete from database where column is no matter?

For example I have that table

Table **people**:

```
name  | age |
------+-----+
James |  20 | 
Smith |  25 | 
James |  40 |
```

I want to do this:

```
delete from people 
where name = 'James' 
  and age = *;
```

I know that I can do:

```
delete from people 
where name = 'James'
```

But I do not need this

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use the second option.  It's *exactly* what you want to do...  If the column doesn't matter, don't include it as a filter...

Comment: what do you mean column is no matter?

Comment: and age > -1 an option? This even check if age is valid before being displayed.

Comment: you could do `age in(select age from people)`, which would include every age, this way you could successfully include an unncessesary part of code there :) No sersiously if you don´t mind for the age, just leave it out of the `where` condition.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
DELETE FROM people where
name like '%personsname%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to a parameter that can be NULL then use it like this

```
delete from people
where name = @nameParam
and (@ageParam is null or age = @ageParam)
```